# Failed to start Elasticsearch (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

when i try to start

`$ sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service'`

i get

'Job for elasticsearch.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.'

```
$ sudo systemctl status elasticsearch.service

elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendo>
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Sat 2021-02-27 14:54:55 IST; 2min 3>
       Docs: https://www.elastic.co
    Process: 46711 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint ->
   Main PID: 46711 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Feb 27 14:54:35 aasif-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Feb 27 14:54:55 aasif-desktop systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process >
Feb 27 14:54:55 aasif-desktop systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with r>
Feb 27 14:54:55 aasif-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
```

Comment: check the log file of elasticsearch. default is /var/log/elasticsearch or you can check in /etc/elasticsearch/*.conf for log file path. from the log you will be able to find the exact problem.

Comment: I have just come across this problem. Is reboot the only solution?